# Custom setters in s3 r

Tags: r

This is the way I intend to define a S3 method for setting s3 attributes

```
a <- 1L

mynames <- function(x) attr(x,"mynames")
`mynames<-` <- function(x,value) {
  eval(substitute(`attr<-`(x,"mynames",value),
                  list(x=match.call()$x,value=value)),
       parent.frame(),parent.frame())
}


mynames(a)
# NULL
mynames(a) <- "a"
mynames(a)
# [1] "a"
```

It seems to work. However, as it looks a bit forced, I wonder if there are more direct (safer ?) methods of doing that. The problem is that base `names<-` and `dimnames<-` are primitive functions, hence it's impossible to make the same code.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with S3

Comment: @HongOoi not with the class system dispatch but attr are the old S3 attributes hence the problem is to emulate a method that modifies objects in the  s3 paradigm

Comment: Attributes have nothing to do with S3. In fact, it's S4 properties that are implemented as attributes, not S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit less forced to use `assign`:

```r
`mynames<-` <- function(x, value) {
  assign(deparse(substitute(x)), `attr<-`(x, "mynames", value), parent.frame())
}
```